# Can tension force be negative?

Tags: forces, gravity, mass

Imagine we have a box (mass = 5kg) attached to a rope:

[image]

Considering gravity as $ 9.8m/s^2$, if we decelerate the box at $ 10.8m/s^2$, the tension force (of the rope) can be calculated like this:

$T = m (g-a)$

$T = 5 (9.8-10.8)$

$T = -5N$

Now is it possible to have a negative tension force?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either the situation can not arise (a rope or chain can't support negative tension, while a strut can) – or you messed up the direction of your forces (e.g. because the force of deceleration and gravity should act in the same direction).

In the first case this means that the deceleration can't happen due to the rope: You left the parameter space where your model of the physical situation is valid.

So have a good look at the task again.

Remark: Never forget the units in your equations.

Answer (score 3):

You defined gravity to be acting in the positive direction (down) and the decelerating tension force to be in the negative direction (up). A negative result merely means that tension is pulling up on the box, against gravity which is pulling down on the box. A negative force is simply one that acts in a direction opposite to a positive force. You could have flipped the problem definition to have down be the negative direction and up be positive - the solution would have flipped signs, but that would be by convention only and would represent the same physical system.

Note that no matter how you define your coordinate system, you can always find a negative tension force somewhere in the complete system - a rope pulling on something at one end must pull equally hard in the opposite direction on the other end. Two teams in a tug of war are both pulled by the rope equally hard, but in opposite directions. In this scenario, if the box is pulled up by negative tension, it must pull down on whatever is holding the rope with equal and opposite positive tension. Even if you flip the signs, one must be positive and the other negative.

Answer (score 1):

Tension on a body (rope, concrete, etc.) is a force that tends to stretch the body.  A compressive force tends to compress the body.  Force is a vector, and the direction for a tension force is always in the stretching direction; that direction can be positive or negative or at some angle to an axis depending on how you define your three Cartesian coordinates, as other answers point out.

For example, consider a rope running along your x axis with +x defined as to the right and -x to the left. A horse pulls on each end of the rope with the same force, so the rope is stationary. For any segment of the rope, the tension force on the right end of the segment is in the positive x direction and the tension force on the left end of the segment is in the negative x direction; the two tensions are equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to maintain the segment stationary.